# Nested RecyclerView with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter and LifecycleOwner doesn't populate

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components

I am trying to have a nested RecyclerView where a Horizontal RecyclerView will be shown as an item of Vertical RecyclerView. (UI looks similar to Google Play Store)

Since my dataset is in FirebaseFirestore, I am using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter to achieve this.

My Fragment's code (Parent RecyclerView exists here):

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview, container, false)
    val query = <some reference>
    val recycler = view.recyclerView
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter = DashboardAdapter(this,
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().categoryOption(query, this),
            R.layout.item_dashboard_row)
    recycler.adapter = adapter
    return view
}
```

DashboardAdapter snippet:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DashboardHolder {
    val item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(layout, parent, false)
    return DashboardHolder(item)
}
```

DashboardHolder snippet:

```
internal class DashboardHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {

private val rowTitle: TextView = item.rowTitle
private val rowRecycler: RecyclerView = item.rowRecycler

fun bind(category: Category, owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    rowTitle.text = category.name
    rowRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val query = <some query>
    val adapter = DashboardProductsAdapter(
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                    .productOption(query, owner),
            R.layout.item_dashboard_product)
    rowRecycler.adapter = adapter
}
}
```

It's clear that DashboardHolder(the parent view holder) has RecyclerView in it. And while binding, the child adapter is created and set to the child RecyclerView.

When I am loading the Fragment for the first time, everything works fine and loads properly. But after I click Home button and come back to the app again, only the parent RecyclerView is getting populated, not the child ones.

After I started digging more, figured out that it's because of `LifecycleOwner` I am passing while creating `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`. If I don't set it and manually call `startListening()` and `stopListening()`, then also the behavior is same. But if I don't call `stopListening()`, it works fine.

Updated Fragment's code:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    adapter.startListening()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    // If I comment this out, everything works fine
    // But putting this in code doesn't populate the child RecyclerView 2nd time
    adapter.stopListening()
}
```

What could be the possible problem? Shall I create the child adapter outside the bind() method? Shall I skip `stopListening()` callback, but this might lead to memory leak.

Comment: Hi @Chandra Sekhar, I am facing the same issue with Firestore RecyclerView, in my case I call nested recycler view's adapter.startListening() in onBindViewHolder of the parent RecyclerView and never call the adapter.stopListening(). The application works fine for a while, but starts to hang and ultimately crash, I think this might be because adapter.startListening() is called multiple times without being stopped which leads to memory leak.
Have you found any solution for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several things that could be going wrong here. I'll update this answer once we figure it out.

First, I want to make sure you're calling `bind()` in `onBindViewHolder()`, right?

Next, I'm pretty sure this doesn't matter, but could you move your init code to `onViewCreated()` like so:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val query = <some reference>
    val recycler = view.recyclerView
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter = DashboardAdapter(this,
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Category>().categoryOption(query, this),
            R.layout.item_dashboard_row)
    recycler.adapter = adapter
}
```

As for your view holders, there's one core problem you'll need to solve which is a little tricky to think about. `bind()` is going to be called numerous times between `onStart()` and `onStop` which means you're going to be left with a large number of hanging adapters because `stopListening()` won't be called when an adapter is rebound. To get around this, you'll need to save your adapter in a property and clear it every time in `bind()` like so:

```
private var currentAdapter: FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<...>? = null

fun bind(...) {
    currentAdapter?.let {
        it.stopListening() // Stop listening to database
        lifecycle.removeObserver(it) // Prevent automatic readdition of listeners
    }

    // Init adapter
    currentAdapter = ...
}
```

If none of the above works, you'll need to do some hardcore debugging by stepping through your code bit by bit until you see where things are falling apart. These are the breakpoints I would  suggest adding:

1. The adapter's `startListening()` method, ensure `addChangeEventListener()` is called
2. The adapter's `onChildChanged()` method, ensure it's being called with correct values
3. Walk the stack to look through your memory and ensure the references you're holding are the current objects and not ghosts from `onStop()`
4. Everything is being called in the right place? Probably not a FirebaseUI or Architecture Components issue. BTW, ensure you're on the latest FUI version `3.1.0` and AAC version `rc1`.

Comment: Below exception with latest FUI: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter]
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.j.a(Lifecycling.java:111)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.j.a(Lifecycling.java:57)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.h$a.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:346)
                      at android.arch.lifecycle.h.a(LifecycleRegistry.java:162)
                      at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.<init>(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:37)

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to be a different issue altogether. Make sure you're using support lib 26.1.x and try running `./gradlew clean`. Not sure what could be going there.

Comment: Yes support library is 26.1.0 and already tried cleaning project. My app only runs with arch-components 1.0.0-beta1 with FUI 3.0.0. Whenever I try to update any one of those, it starts crashing.

Comment: Hmmm, could you create a GitHub issue with deobfuscated stack traces?

Comment: It only happens with proguard enabled apk. Please see the last comment of this issue. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46

Comment: This also happened to me. Place @Keep annotation just above your Model Class.

Answer (score 0):

I just called setHasFixedSize(false) on both recyclerView objects, and it's working for me.